How to fix no such module vfio-pci?
I am trying to change the driver of my gpu to vfio. This is the command I use
sudo driverctl set-override 0000:28:00.0 vfio-pci

Here is the error
driverctl: no such module: vfio-pci


Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Seems that you still need to install the module. Following https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/linux-on-systems?topic=setup-pci you can do this with:
modprobe vfio_pci ids=<vendor_code>:<device_code>

